# YOLO darknet vs darkflow

Tags: yolo, darknet, darkflow

Can anyone please help me to distinguish between darknet and darkflow. Advantages of one over the other. My understanding about YOLO (You Only Look Once) is an algorithm for fast object detection.

Answer (score 7):

Darknet is the name of the framework YOLO is originally implemented on.
Note DarkNet-XX (XX=19/51) is also the name of the backbone YOLO uses.

Darkflow is a nickname of an implementation of YOLO on TensorFlow.